# Python boto3 s3 library returns different dictionaries to the official documentation

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm finding a frustrating mis-match between the official documentation of boto3 (https://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Bucket.create) and what is returned in practice.

Just to make sure, I'm using boto3 1.2.1 and botocore 1.3.2 (both installed with pip).

I'm specifically talking about creating a bucket using the `boto3.Session` method:

```
import boto3
session = boto3.Session(region_name = 'us-west-2', \
                    aws_access_key_id = 'AAA', \
                    aws_secret_access_key = 'BBB')
s3 = session.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('testbucket').create()
```

I'm told in the documentation that the the `s3.Bucket('testbucket').create()` command returns a dictionary that looks like

```
{
    'Location': 'string'
}
```

but instead I get a dictionary that looks like:

```
{
    u'Location': '/testbucket',
    'ResponseMetadata': {
        'HTTPStatusCode': 200,
        'HostId': 'alphnumericalmixed/alphanumericalmixed',
        'RequestId': 'MIXEDUPPERANDNUMBERS123'
    }
}
```

I get a similar thing if I try to delete an S3 object too by invoking its `delete()` method, e.g.:

```
# some initialisation as above code
obj=bucket.put_object(Body='123', Key='456')
print obj.delete()
```

where I get:

```
{'ResponseMetadata': 
{'HTTPStatusCode': 204, 
'HostId': 'something/something', 
'RequestId': 'SOMETHING'}}
```

instead of (https://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Object.delete):

```
{
'DeleteMarker': True|False,
'VersionId': 'string',
'RequestCharged': 'requester'
}
```

I know that boto3 is an involved wrapper of the botocore library, and the `RequestID` key in the dictionary I'm getting back ultimately comes from `botocore/parsers.py`. I understand the `create` return as it actually has additional information, but what I don't understand is that the `put_object()` method return **doesn't contain any similar to the documentation**

**What I'm trying to work out is whether the official documentation is lying to me.**

Comment: Why the -1? At least justify it.

Comment: The docs are not lying, they just won't return anything when there's nothing to return. There was no versioning, so no version id or delete marker. There was no 'RequestCharged' sent with the request, so nothing there either.

Comment: Right, so +1 for terse ambiguous documentation then. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jordan Phillips says:

"The docs are not lying, they just won't return anything when there's nothing to return. There was no versioning, so no version id or delete marker. There was no 'RequestCharged' sent with the request, so nothing there either."

I guess this was one thing I was not expecting. I assumed that the return dictionary would only contain the documented values, rather than additional ones.